# React-redux connect: root component connect vs multiple connects

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've been using connect in such a way:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Where `Home` is the root component and I was told it's wrong to pass all props
down the components tree.
So, I ought to use another approach:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DayContainer);
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SwitchersContainer);
// ------------------------------
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WeekContainer);
```

As for the former approach, it's way more convinient and 
maintainable, less laborous, less verbose.
Is there any advantage in the latter one, 
apart from pushing fewer props down the components tree?

Comment: My question is not about "How". My question is about from "Best practice" point of view.  Of course, I can do it both ways.